# How to display on a map the detected beacon？

Tags: ios7, dictionary, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

I can receive and send signals iBeacon now.
I want to make a simple model for indoor positioning,but very few references I could find. 
How to display itself in xcode 5 devices and detected ibeacon on the map (represented by two points)?
Thanks.

Comment: iBeacons don't carry location data, only proximity. Perhaps you could come up with an algorithm based on current location and beacon signal strength, but at this time, you can't simply get a coordinate from an iBeacon.

Comment: with each proximity you should have x,y coordinates, so once you get proximity just check with your database or cache is this known beacon which has x,y coordinates if yes then you can do what ever you want.